# TSLtoRGB colorspace conversion

Tags: math, color-space

Someone knows the correct formula for RGBtoTSL ?

Wikipedia says that the conversion between RGB and TSL is made like this:
[image]

But....the reverse transformation presented on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TSL_color_space is incorrect. The results presented by their reverted formula are not correct.

What is the proper formula to revert the transformation back ? I.e: transforming from TSL to RGB ?

Serg, here is some attempts we are making to try the revert operation :) Examples in Asm (RosAsm assembler).

```
; used variables
[Float_YIQ_Red_M1: R$ 0.29889531
Float_YIQ_Green_M2: R$  0.58662247
Float_YIQ_Blue_M3: R$  0.11448223]
[Float_minusOneThird: R$ (-1/3)] ; error in RosAsm. It can´ see "-(1/3)"
[r1Factor: R$ 0]
[g1Factor: R$ 0]
[rFactor: R$ 0]
[gFactor: R$ 0]
[TmpFloat: R$ 0]
[Float_Var95: R$ (9/5)]
[Float_Var14: R$ (1/4)]
[Float_Var34: R$ (3/4)]
[Float_VarOne2Pi: R$ 0.159154943091895335768883763372514362034459645740456448747] ; 1/(2*pi)
[xFactor: R$ 0]
[kFactor: R$ 0]
[Float_Half: R$ 0.5]
[Float_Var59: R$ (5/9)]
[Float_Var53SquareRoot: R$ 0.745355992499929898803057889577092078480206119870508574756] ; sqrt(5)/3
[Float_OneThird: R$ (1/3)]
[FloatTSLVar1: R$ 0.184413]
[FloatTSLVar2: R$ 0.4721403]
[Float_TempRed: R$ 0]
[Float_TempGreen: R$ 0]
[Float_TempBlue: R$ 0]
[Float_Two_PI: R$ 6.283185307179586476925286766559005768394338798750211641948]
[Float_Five: R$ 5.0]
; -----------------------------------------------------------
Proc RGBtoTSL2a:
    Arguments @PixelSrc, @Tint, @Saturation, @Light
    Local @TempRed, @TempGreen, @TempBlue, @TempCmax, @TempCmin, @TempDelta_Max, @TempVar
    Uses eax, ecx, esi, edi, edx, ebx

finit
; RGB from 0 to 255
; get RED
mov esi D@PixelSrc | movzx edi B$esi+ARGB.RedDis | lea ecx D@TempRed | mov D$ecx edi | mov eax edi
; get GREEN
mov esi D@PixelSrc | movzx edi B$esi+ARGB.GreenDis | lea ecx D@TempGreen | mov D$ecx edi | add eax edi
; get BLUE
mov esi D@PixelSrc | movzx edi B$esi+ARGB.BlueDis | lea ecx D@TempBlue | mov D$ecx edi | add eax edi

If eax = 0
    fldz
    mov esi D@Light | fst R$esi
    mov esi D@Saturation | fst R$esi
    mov esi D@Tint | fstp R$esi
    ExitP
End_If

; Get Min and Max of RGB (just to get MIn/Max RGB to check for grey
lea ebx D@TempCmin | mov D$ebx 0
lea eax D@TempCmax | mov D$eax 0
call GetRGB_MinMax esi, ebx, eax

; Get Delta
; max = edx
; min = ecx
mov edx D@TempCmax | lea eax D@TempCmax | mov D$eax edx
mov ecx D@TempCmin | lea eax D@TempCmin | mov D$eax ecx
lea ebx D@TempDelta_Max | mov D$ebx 0; cmax-cmin
mov eax D@TempCmax | sub eax D@TempCMin | mov D$ebx eax

; 1st compute Light (Normalized)
mov esi D@Light
fild F@TempRed | fmul R$Float_YIQ_Red_M1
fild F@TempGreen | fmul R$Float_YIQ_Green_M2
faddp ST1 ST0
fild F@TempBlue | fmul R$Float_YIQ_Blue_M3
faddp ST1 ST0 | fmul R$FloatOne_255 | fstp R$esi

..If D@TempDelta_Max = 0; This is gray, no tint, no saturation
    fldz
    mov esi D@Saturation | fst R$esi
    mov esi D@Tint | fstp R$esi
..Else
    ; 2nd compute Saturation

    ; get rfactor
    lea edi D@TempVar
    fild F@TempRed | fiadd F@TempGreen | fiadd F@TempBlue | fistp F$edi

    fild F@TempRed | fidiv F$edi | fadd R$Float_minusOneThird | fstp R$rFactor

    ; get gfactor
    fild F@TempGreen | fidiv F$edi | fadd R$Float_minusOneThird | fstp R$gFactor

    mov esi D@Saturation
    fld R$rFactor | fmul ST0 ST0
    fld R$gFactor | fmul ST0 ST0
    faddp ST1 ST0 | fmul R$Float_Var95
    fsqrt | fstp R$esi

    ; 3rd compute Tint

    mov esi D@Tint
    fldz | fstp R$esi
    fld R$rFactor | fdiv R$gFactor | fstp R$TmpFloat

    Fpu_If R$gFactor > R$Float_Zero
        fld R$TmpFloat | fld1 | fpatan | fmul R$Float_VarOne2Pi | fadd R$Float_Var14 | fstp R$esi ; result in radian
    Fpu_Else_If R$gFactor < R$Float_Zero
        fld R$TmpFloat | fld1 | fpatan | fmul R$Float_VarOne2Pi | fadd R$Float_Var34 | fstp R$esi ; result in radian
    Fpu_End_If

..End_If

EndP
```

and the reverted function

```
Proc TSLtoRGB2a:
    Arguments @Tint, @Saturation, @Light, @Red, @Green, @Blue
    Local @TempRed, @TempGreen, @TempBlue
    Uses eax, ecx, esi, edi, ebx


; check for light conditions
mov esi D@Light
Fpu_If R$esi = R$Float_Zero
    mov edi D@Red | mov D$edi 0
    mov edi D@Green | mov D$edi 0
    mov edi D@Blue | mov D$edi 0
    ExitP
Fpu_End_If

mov edi D@Saturation
mov esi D@Tint
;.Fpu_If_Or R$esi = R$Float_Zero, R$edi = R$Float_Zero ; Grey color found
; Not true. Tint = 0 not necessarily means grey. What means grey is 
; saturation = 0
; see Serg examples:(44, 22, 0) and (0, 32, 64)

.Fpu_If R$edi = R$Float_Zero ; Grey color found. Seems to be only this case for finding grey.
    mov ebx D@Light
    fld R$ebx | fst R$Float_TempRed | fst R$Float_TempGreen | fstp R$Float_TempBlue
    fld1 | fstp R$kFactor
.Fpu_Else
    ; compute -1 * cot(2*pi*Tint)
    fld R$esi
    fmul R$Float_Two_PI
    fptan
    fdivrp ST0 ST1
    fmul R$Float_Minus_one
    fstp R$xFactor

    fld1 | fld R$xFactor | fmul ST0 ST0 | fadd R$Float_One | fdivp ST0 ST1 | fmul R$Float_Five
    fsqrt | fmul R$Float_OneThird | fmul R$edi | fstp R$g1Factor
    Fpu_If R$esi > R$Float_Half
        fld R$g1Factor | fmul R$Float_Minus_One  | fstp R$g1Factor
    Fpu_End_If

    fld R$g1Factor | fmul R$xFactor | fstp R$r1Factor

    fld R$r1Factor | fadd R$Float_OneThird | fstp R$Float_TempRed
    fld R$g1Factor | fadd R$Float_OneThird | fstp R$Float_TempGreen
    fld1 | fsub R$Float_TempRed | fsub R$Float_TempGreen | fstp R$Float_TempBlue

    ; Compte KFactor
    mov ebx D@Light
    fld R$ebx
    fld R$Float_TempRed | fmul R$FloatTSLVar1
    fld R$Float_TempGreen | fmul R$FloatTSLVar2
    faddp ST1 ST0 | fadd R$Float_YIQ_Blue_M3
    fdivp ST1 ST0
    fstp R$kFactor

.Fpu_End_If

mov edi D@Red | fld R$kFactor | fmul R$Float_TempRed | fmul R$Float255 | fistp F$edi
If D$edi <s 0
    mov D$edi 0
Else_If D$edi > 255
    mov D$edi 255
End_If
mov edi D@Green | fld R$kFactor | fmul R$Float_TempGreen | fmul R$Float255 | fistp F$edi
If D$edi <s 0
    mov D$edi 0
Else_If D$edi > 255
    mov D$edi 255
End_If
mov edi D@Blue | fld R$kFactor | fmul R$Float_TempBlue | fmul R$Float255 | fistp F$edi
If D$edi <s 0
    mov D$edi 0
Else_If D$edi > 255 ; something still is incorrect.
                    ; See what happens when:
                    ; Tint = 0.85764542031
                    ; Saturation: 0.0315199340953953
                    ; Light = 0.8826082107058823529411764705882352941176

    mov D$edi 255
End_If

EndP
```

Comment: guga, do you have some specific examples. where you believe the formula to be wrong? Could you share them?

Comment: Hi Serg, thanks for reply; Yes,  try inputing this: Red = 128, Green = 22, Blue = 37 and once you find the TSL, try the reverse formula and you will see that it produced incorrect values (one of them negative, btw, which is impossible on rgb). Also, on wiki, there is a tab labeled "talk" where people can comment. The person who made the reversed formula said it was incorrect and he "guessed" it and other people tested and the result is incorrect. Some of them posted a excel to show the error https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aeX8yPvRmiM5JhScvGx2Ub9CV1Sh8CVC4Kho7flwsKo/edit#gid=162141974

Comment: Btw...if someone wants to test, the values of 1/4 and 3/4 in Tint are outside the arctangent. So to compute T is arctang(r'/g') divide the reult by 2*PI and tenn add 1/4 or 3/4 accordlly

Answer (score 1):

Code was **updated** with a "negative zero" trick to handle `T = 0` case

It is too big for a comment so I'll put it as an answer. I think that the formula at the wiki is correct and works OK in cases except `2 * G == R + B` (i.e. except `g' == 0` or in other words `T == 0`) in which case backward transformation is not unique mathematically. But in practice since we have both [positive and negative zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) on our hardware, we can use them do distinguish those bad cases.

Here is almost literal transformation of that formula into a JS:

```
function rgbFromTsl(T, S, L) {
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        T = arguments[0][0];
        S = arguments[0][1];
        L = arguments[0][2];
    }

    if (L == 0)
        return [0, 0, 0];

    var r1, g1, x;
    var r, g, b;

    // For T == 0 reverse solution is not unique
    // and we use a trick with "negative zero" to distinguish them
    if (isNegativeZero(T)) {
        g1 = 0;
        r1 = -Math.sqrt(5.0) / 3.0 * S;

    }
    else if (T == 0) {
        g1 = 0;
        r1 = Math.sqrt(5.0) / 3.0 * S;
    }
    else {

        x = -1.0 / Math.tan(2 * Math.PI * T);
        g1 = Math.sqrt(5.0 / (1 + x * x)) / 3.0 * S;
        if (T > 0.5)
            g1 = -g1;
        r1 = x * g1;
    }
    r = r1 + 1.0 / 3;
    g = g1 + 1.0 / 3;
    b = (1 - r - g);
    var k = L / (0.185 * r + 0.473 * g + 0.114);
    return [k * r, k * g, k * b];
}
```

and for the example you provided

> try inputing this: Red = 128, Green = 22, Blue = 37 and once you find the TSL, try the reverse formula and you will see that it produced incorrect values (one of them negative, btw, which is impossible on rgb).

it seems to produce back the original R, G, B values with a quite good precision.

Here is a full runnable code that you can run just in place and play with some values. Let me know if you find some other bad cases except for `2*G = R+B` aka `T = 0`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TSL/RGB</title>
    <style>
        div {
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #container {
            width: 550px;
        }
        
        input {
            width: 150px;
        }

        #lc, #rc {
            width: 220px;
            border: dashed;
        }

        #lc {
            float: left;
        }

        #rc {
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="lc">
        <h1>RGB to TSL</h1>

        <form name="RGBsrc">
            <div id="RGBsrc">
                <div>
                    <label for="Rsrc">R=</label> <input type="number" id="Rsrc" value="128">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Gsrc">G=</label> <input type="number" id="Gsrc" value="22">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Bsrc">B=</label> <input type="number" id="Bsrc" value="37">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="TSLdst">

                <div>
                    <label for="Tdst">T=</label> <input type="number" id="Tdst" disabled="disabled">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Sdst">S=</label> <input type="number" id="Sdst" disabled="disabled">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Ldst">L=</label> <input type="number" id="Ldst" disabled="disabled">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div><button id="btnRgbToTsl">RGB to TSL</button></div>
            <div><button id="btnCopyTsl">Copy result to TSL</button></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="rc">
        <h1>TSL to RGB</h1>

        <form name="TSLsrc">
            <div id="TSLsrc">
                <div>
                    <label for="Tsrc">T=</label> <input type="number" id="Tsrc" value="0.5876633198969483">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Ssrc">S=</label> <input type="number" id="Ssrc" value="0.552900835318196">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Lsrc">L=</label> <input type="number" id="Lsrc" value="55.403999999999996">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="RGBdst">

                <div>
                    <label for="Rdst">R=</label> <input type="number" id="Rdst" disabled="disabled">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Gdst">G=</label> <input type="number" id="Gdst" disabled="disabled">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Bdst">B=</label> <input type="number" id="Bdst" disabled="disabled">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="roundRgbDst">Round RGB</label> <input type="checkbox" id="roundRgbDst" checked="checked" style="width: 50px;" >
            </div>

            <button id="btnTslToRgb">TSL to RGB</button>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

function isNegativeZero(v) {
    return 1 / v === -Infinity;
}

function floatToStrSmart(v) {
    if (isNegativeZero(v))
        return "-0.0";
    else
        return "" + v;
}

function parseFloatSmart(s) {
    if ((s === "-0") || (s === "-0.0"))
        return -0.0;
    else
        return parseFloat(s)

}

function tslFromRgb(R, G, B) {
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        R = arguments[0][0];
        G = arguments[0][1];
        B = arguments[0][2];
    }
    if ((R == 0) && (G == 0) && (B == 0)) {
        return [0, 0, 0];
    }
    var L = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B;
    var r1 = R / (R + G + B) - 1.0 / 3;
    var g1 = G / (R + G + B) - 1.0 / 3;

    var S = Math.sqrt(9.0 / 5 * (r1 * r1 + g1 * g1));
    var T;
    if (g1 == 0) {
        if (R < B)
            T = -0.0;
        else
            T = 0.0
    }
    else {
        T = Math.atan(r1 / g1) / Math.PI / 2 + 0.25;
        if (g1 < 0)
            T += 0.5;
    }

    return [T, S, L]
}


function rgbFromTsl(T, S, L) {
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        T = arguments[0][0];
        S = arguments[0][1];
        L = arguments[0][2];
    }

    if (L == 0)
        return [0, 0, 0];

    var r1, g1, x;
    var r, g, b;

    // For T == 0 reverse solution is not unique
    // and we use a trick with "negative zero" to distinguish them
    if (isNegativeZero(T)) {
        g1 = 0;
        r1 = -Math.sqrt(5.0) / 3.0 * S;

    }
    else if (T == 0) {
        g1 = 0;
        r1 = Math.sqrt(5.0) / 3.0 * S;
    }
    else {

        x = -1.0 / Math.tan(2 * Math.PI * T);
        g1 = Math.sqrt(5.0 / (1 + x * x)) / 3.0 * S;
        if (T > 0.5)
            g1 = -g1;
        r1 = x * g1;
    }
    r = r1 + 1.0 / 3;
    g = g1 + 1.0 / 3;
    b = (1 - r - g);
    var k = L / (0.185 * r + 0.473 * g + 0.114);
    return [k * r, k * g, k * b];
}

document.getElementById('btnRgbToTsl').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var r = parseInt(document.getElementById('Rsrc').value);
    var g = parseInt(document.getElementById('Gsrc').value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('Bsrc').value);

    document.getElementById('Rsrc').value = r;
    document.getElementById('Gsrc').value = g;
    document.getElementById('Bsrc').value = b;

    var tsl = tslFromRgb(r, g, b);
    var t = tsl[0];
    var s = tsl[1];
    var l = tsl[2];

    document.getElementById('Tdst').value = floatToStrSmart(t);
    document.getElementById('Sdst').value = s;
    document.getElementById('Ldst').value = l;

});

document.getElementById('btnCopyTsl').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('Tsrc').value = document.getElementById('Tdst').value;
    document.getElementById('Ssrc').value = document.getElementById('Sdst').value;
    document.getElementById('Lsrc').value = document.getElementById('Ldst').value;
});


document.getElementById('btnTslToRgb').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = parseFloatSmart(document.getElementById('Tsrc').value);
    var s = parseFloat(document.getElementById('Ssrc').value);
    var l = parseFloat(document.getElementById('Lsrc').value);

    document.getElementById('Tsrc').value = floatToStrSmart(t);
    document.getElementById('Ssrc').value = s;
    document.getElementById('Lsrc').value = l;


    var rgb = rgbFromTsl(t, s, l);
    var r = rgb[0];
    var g = rgb[1];
    var b = rgb[2];

    if (document.getElementById('roundRgbDst').checked) {
        document.getElementById('Rdst').value = (r + .1) | 0; //round to int
        document.getElementById('Gdst').value = (g + .1) | 0; //round to int;
        document.getElementById('Bdst').value = (b + .1) | 0; //round to int;;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('Rdst').value = r;
        document.getElementById('Gdst').value = g;
        document.getElementById('Bdst').value = b;
    }

});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent work, Serge :) How did you manage to fix the problems found on wiki ? Btw, i´m testing it, and i´m fixing the problem of the 2*G = R+B and T = 0. Just finishing some tests before posting :)  Many thanks :)

Comment: @guga, I think my code is exactly the same as the formulas on the wiki except for additional handling of case when `L` is 0. As for unique back transformations when `T` is 0, I don't think it is really possible without strange tricks such as expecting `R`, `G` and `B` to be exactly whole integers. As an example you can see that RGBs `(44, 22, 0)` and `(0, 32, 64)` produce very similar TSL `(0, 0.4472, 26.07)` and `(0, 0.4472, 26.08)`. They are very hard to distinguish during reverse transformation. Obviously the reason for this is that when `T=0` we loose the sign of `r'` .

Comment: I believe your code is a small improvement, because the original excel file used to test on wiki is utterly incorrect. The problem of T = 0 happens not only when g'=0. The original formula forgot to consider the grey scale. So, for RGBtoTSL T = 0 when g'=0 and s'=0. And on this situation only happens when R = G=B. And also on this situations (for grey) when T= 0, Saturation = 0 too. Doing this will fix the cases for R = (B+G)/2 and R = 2 G - B that was the original conditions for g'=0.

Comment: I made those fixes on the RGBtoTSL and the revert formula worked ok. And for the reverted formula, the condition is similar. So, whenever T = 0 or S = 0 then we have found a grey color. So, we only need to compute the color back from Light. So, Red = Green = Blue = Light (or multiplying by 255 if it is normalized). I don´t know how to post code here to show you. How can i insert new code here in the comments ?

Comment: Another thing. I used the YIQ colorspace values and not the general 0.299R+0.587G+0.114B as in the formula. I used this, instead: 0.29889531*R + 0.58662247+G+ 0.11448223*B. Since, i made  slight adjust on this color data, i´m trying to find the proper reverted values from TSLtoRGB. he used as k = L/(0.185r+0.473g+.0114). I´m trying to understand how he found the values of 0.185 or 0.473 to adjust properly to the YIQ values for gain more accuracy. It is working with these values

Comment: Sorry...i made a typo before...I meant..." So, for RGBtoTSL T = 0 when g'=0 and r'=0. And on this situation only happens when R = G=B. And also on this situations (for grey) when T= 0, Saturation = 0 too"

Comment: @guga, you can't post code into the comments but you can edit your question to add code there. As for "issues with greyscale", I just don't understand what are those issues. If `T=S=0`, then `R=G=B=L` and it already works OK in my code. So what's the issue? As for coefficients for `k`, they are easy to get. `b = 1 - r - g`, so if `L = x*R + y*G + z*B`, then `L/(R+G+B) = x*r + y*g + z*(1-r-g) = (x-z)*r + (y-z)*g + z`, thus `k = R+G+B = L/((x-z)*r + (y-z)*g + z)`. So `0.185 = 0.299 - 0.114` and `0.473 = 0.587 - 0.114`. Just put your values for `x`, `y` and `z` and you'll get the result

Comment: Thanks...I´ll try to edit and post the code. About the issues were these ones: "Let me know if you find some other bad cases except for 2*G = R+B aka T = 0" Those cases the original algorithm is incorrect. Even when those values are achieved T is not 0. The only situation T=0 (and, therefore, S is also 0) are when we are dealing with grey. Form the original algo if you insert this: Red 150, Green 100, Blue 200 (R = (B+G)/2) or these Red 100, Green 87, Blue 74 ( 2*G = R+B) then the algorithm will fail..But...this is incorrect. Your algo  works for those situations :) What´s wrong is wiki nfo

Comment: @guga, I don't think I understand what you mean. `T=0` **_is_** `G = (R+B)/2`.  Have you considered my example about `(44, 22, 0)` and `(0, 32, 64)` which produce almost identical TLS representations, both having `T=0`? I also don't understand where exactly wiki fails for your `Red 150, Green 100, Blue 200`. Could you be more specific? AFAICS `T=0.75` is not a bad case in anyway because **_cotangent_** (unlike **_tangent_**) is well defined for that value and is 0.

Comment: Yes, T=0, according to wiki is G = (R+B)/2, but...what wiki failed is that assuming  T=0 (no tint) is the case where G = (R+B)/2, but this is incorrect. No tint does not means grey, but no saturation does means grey. On my tests your example (44, 22, 0) results on T = 0.5 and (0, 32, 64) results on T=6.6318e-18 (almost zero). On both cases it produces the reverted value. (I coded in asm using Double instead of integer). With your values, i found that, in fact, T can have any value (zero included) to the revert operation works, but, what can´t be zero is only Saturation, because S=0 is grey.

Comment: I´ll try to post here the functions in asm to you see. Another thing...try using this: T= 0.85764542031, S=0.0315199340953953, L=225.06509373. The values found on RGB are being extrapolated somehow. Blue is marking to be 256 and not 255 as it should. I´m trying to find where it failed using these values on the reverted function (TLStoRGB). There should be some limits we are not seeing.

Comment: @guga, you obviously put to much trust into your code without critical thinking. For both `(44, 22, 0)` and `(0, 32, 64)` `g` is exactly `1/3` = `22/(44+22+0)` = `32/(0+32+64)` and thus `g'` is exactly `0`. Obviously your code doesn't calculate the value of `g'` exactly and thus you get wrong values of almost `0` and almost `1/2` (which actualy corresponds to a kind of `g' = -0`). But the fact that you have rounding errors in your code that are luckily produce differently signed small value for `g'` instead of 0 for this particular case doesn't make reverse transformation unique.

Comment: as for "_what wiki failed is that assuming T=0 (no tint) is the case where G = (R+B)/2, but this is incorrect. No tint does not means grey, but no saturation does means grey._" I still don't understand you. Wiki does not mention word "grey" or "gray" at all. So what's wrong with wiki? As for your last example, you probably mistakenly assume that all triplets TSL with T and S in range [0-1] and L in range [0-256] correspond to some valid RGB triplet but this is not true. Some of just T-S combinations are impossible and this is all the more so for T-S-L. Also remember about rounding errors.

Comment: But, this is what i´m tying to tell you (Sorry, English is not my native language). The fact that g result in 1/3 and g' in 0 is not a reason for the algo (in wiki) can´t produce the revert operation. The only reason seems that, T beign 0 is not relevant to the algo stop the revert operation. It only means that the angle 0 (T=0) can be found whenever  2*G = R+B,but....when Saturation = 0 (and, by consequence, r' is also 0), the only possible solution is it found a true grey color. Unfortunately there is little literature on the algo, but, we are on the right way to it be more robust, i think

Comment: here is the conversation on wiki were they found errors and talked about the lack of literature. Not sure if you can read the "talk" tab, so, here is a print: http://i66.tinypic.com/aw94j4.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143199/discussion-between-serggr-and-guga).